# How to stream data from a RDBM to Kafka cluster

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need to fetch data from an Oracle DB into existing topics on an existing Kafka cluster (centrally maintained in my organization) using queries. Since I'm familiar with Java, I could use JDBC to connect to the database and issue queries, create a kafka producer, and use the resultset to populate the topics, however this feels like reinventing the wheel.

Is there a more elegant way of streaming data from a RDBM to Kafka in my usecase? I have looked into Confluent Kafka Connect /w jdbc connectors, but this does not seem to fit the bill since my data sink will be an existing kafka cluster.

Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you expand on this point please? `I’m bound by the contract of the existing Avro schemas.`. I'm not clear why that preempts you from using Kafka Connect.

Comment: Apologies, poor wording / not relevant. I have edited my original post.

Comment: AWS has DMS (database migration service) which reads the Oracle transaction logs and sends to the whatever destination defined. So there is a low-level way. `Kafka Connect /w jdbc connectors.. not seem to fit the bill` why the connector is not enough? You should be able using an existing cluster

Comment: @MrM Check out https://rmoff.dev/no-more-silos for useful background

Answer (score 0):

The Confluent JDBC **Source** writes to any Kafka cluster, exactly like you want, but you shouldn't use JDBC for streaming data unless you are snapshotting the current state of the table and there will be no updates/deletes as you're doing so.

[Debezium supports Oracle](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/oracle.html), otherwise Oracle provides GoldenGate for this purpose.

Comment: I have not found any documention / samples on how to use JDBC to write to "any kafka cluster". Since I have to produce messages to my organizations kafka cluster, my understanding is that this would require a "kafka-cluster sink connector"?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand [the terminology](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/concepts.html). Source connectors write to Kafka (they "source" data from other places into Kafka). Sink connectors write to external resources from Kafka.  The `bootstrap.servers` property in the `connect-distributed.properties` file is the only property that determines where writes/reads happen from. The [blog post here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/) goes over using MySQL, but can easily be adapted to Oracle

Comment: Also, feel free to look at [questions from others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-kafka-connect+oracle) doing the same thing